# I have a problem with jetpack compose textfield and the keyboard autocomplete

Tags: textfield, android-jetpack-compose

While writing in a textfield in compose, when i write a sequence that look like `"something.something"`.
Where `"something"` isn't a white space, the cursor behave strangely.

Here i enter a random word:

[image]

I add the "."

[image]

Here when i enter the new caracter like you can see bellow the word the the first caracter seems to be ignore by the autocorrect

[image]

When i enter the second caracter it is display before the last one

[image]

It continue continue like this

[image]

For the code :

```
val (title, setTitle) = remember { mutableStateOf ("")}
TextField( 
Modifier = Modifier.padding(5.dp),
MaxLines = 1, 
label = {Text(text = "Title")},
value = title, 
onValueChange = setTitle, 
)
```

And my compose version is '1.0.1'

i also try some compose samples like "jetchat" but they does the same thing.

Comment: Post your code or a simple sample to illustrate how you are handling the TextField.

Comment: Thanks for the replay, here is what i do: ```val (title, setTitle) = remember{mutableStateOf("");  TextField(Modifier = Modifier.padding(5.dp), MaxLines= 1, label ={Text(text = "Title")}, value= title, onValueChange = setTitle, keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(imeAction  = ImeAction.Next), keyboardActions = KeyboardActions( onNext = {}))```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the problem came from my Galaxy S7 predictive text functionality when using the French keyboard. Once I change the keyboard to English or removed the predictive text functionality, it worked fine.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You should use rememberSaveable rather than remember